# IDataErrorInfo WPF validation rules / groups

Tags: wpf, validation

I have a Customer Model object that needs different validation rules based on use case. 
For example there are some Properties that depending on the usage of the Customer object are optional other times they are required.
I use attributes for this but it doesnt allow me to specify ruleset. I dont use enterprise library that has this ability.
I can switch to plain IDataErrorInfo for this and pass a property like RuleSet . Is there a better way to achieve this without adding enterprise library ?

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is the solution you are looking for. Instead of hiding a lot of logic inside attributes and rule sets and what not please use sub-classes.

The following example shows a `BaseCustomer` that allows anything but a bad name. The `CustomerWithBadName` needs a bad name.

```
class BaseCustomer : IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public virtual string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public virtual string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;

            if (columnName == "Name")
            {
                if (Name == "Bad name!")
                {
                    result = "Name must not be bad!";
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}

class CustomerWithBadName : BaseCustomer
{
    public override string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public override string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;

            if (columnName == "Name")
            {
                if (Name != "Bad name!")
                {
                    result = "Name must be bad!!!";
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes Both classes would have the property. I thought of this solution but i worry if I have errors generally.

Comment: also how is thing going to work when i have  GetCustomer ? I should duplicate code

Comment: I adjusted my answer. Regarding use cases: You spoke of usage or use cases. Surely you must have code that knows the case and would return the right customer object of the right class.

Comment: ok but this is a pain to implement when there is a rest web service too.And code duplicate for no reason. Most web frameworks support this feature even microsoft enterprise library